# Linux IPsec VPN and SNAT

Tags: linux, vpn, nat, ipsec

I'm trying to connect my network to an IPSec VPN, and for this my connexions need to come from a given domain. The network is the following:

```
Internal network    eth1:10.0.0.1/14      eth0:1.2.3.4
----------------------------------- MY GW -----------------+
                                                           |
                                                           |
             192.168.178.4               4.5.6.7           |
        SERVER ------------------- VPN GW -----------------+
```

I'm required to be seen by the VPN network as coming from 172.30.224.0/28, so on my gateway I've added the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.178.4 -j SNAT --to-source 172.30.224.1
```

Then, from my internal network, when I ping the 192.168.178.4 I get the request on eth1 and the response on eth0:

```
# tcpdump -n -i eth1 host 192.168.178.4
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
15:49:49.854809 IP 10.2.1.172 > 192.168.178.4: ICMP echo request, id 3472, seq 1, length 64
15:49:52.170758 IP 10.2.1.172 > 192.168.178.4: ICMP echo request, id 3479, seq 1, length 64
15:49:53.178692 IP 10.2.1.172 > 192.168.178.4: ICMP echo request, id 3479, seq 2, length 64
# tcpdump -n -i eth0 host 192.168.178.4
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
15:50:36.492856 IP 192.168.178.4 > 172.30.224.1: ICMP echo reply, id 3494, seq 1, length 64
15:50:37.465803 IP 192.168.178.4 > 172.30.224.1: ICMP echo reply, id 3494, seq 2, length 64
```

The problem is that my response never reaches back my host (`10.2.1.172` in this case).

The gateway is also configured to do SNAT for the internal network to internet.

I'm surely missing something here but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the result of the `route` command on your gateway?

Comment: It's also possible that the NAT is working fine but the firewall's not allowing it; could we get the output of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` (on the gateway) in the question as well?

Comment: @Nosax here it is, a little edited to hide the real IPs...

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
1.2.3.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.252.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         1.2.3.5    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0